# Class template with factories

Tags: c++, templates, factory

I am trying to implement a very basic factory pattern in C++, that is

```
class Base {};
class Derived1 : public Base {};
class Derived2 : public Base {};
```

And the usage might look something like

```
Base* o1 = new Derived();
```

However with a class template I am not sure how to proceed

```
template <class T>
class Base {};
template <class T>
class Derived : public Base<int> {};
```

in this case what would the **Base*** look like?

Unfortunately in my case using **auto** is not an option, and I want to be able to free the client from having to know what the actual **T** is

Comment: Do you mean that all Base<T> types should inherit from some common, non-templated, ActualBase?

Comment: _"in this case what would the Base* look like?"_ In this case, you would have to write `Base<int> * o1 = new Derived;` instead... Except if, as suggested [in the above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67370225/class-template-with-factories#comment119079664_67370225), you make your `Base` class inherit a non-templated actual base class.

Comment: @Wyck if I understand correctly you are saying that I should be able to do the following?
class Base {}
template <class T>
class TBAse : public Base {}
template <class T> 
class Derived : public TBase<int>

Base* d = new Derived()?

Answer (score 0):

With

```
template <class T> class Base {};

template <class T>
class Derived : public Base<int> {};
```

you might do

```
Base<int>* b_int = new Derived<char>; // All Derived<T> has base Base<int>
```